# Automatic login to Dropbox server-side

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

**Short version:** Is there a way that my PHP application can login to a certain Dropbox account by doing the complete OAuth 2.0 process server-side?

**Long version:** Consider the following steps:

- Navigate Google Chrome to the login page my Dropbox app: `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?locale=&response_type=code&client_id=[APP_CLIENT_ID]`
- Open Chrome Dev Tools, go to console
- Issue the following jQuery call:

  ```
  jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://www.dropbox.com/ajax_login',
      data: {
          login_email: '[DROPBOX_LOGIN]',
          login_password: '[DROPBOX_PASSWORD]',
          require_role: ''
      },
  });
  ```

Now this browser is logged into Dropbox, which can be seen by refreshing the browser window.

**How can I implement the same procedure in PHP, using cURL or file_get_contents?**

I tried it like this:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

use \Dropbox as dbx;

// init Dropbox login process
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, $clientId);
$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

// load Dropbox login website
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init($authorizeUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

$data = array('login_email' => '[DROPBOX_LOGIN]', 'login_password' => '[DROPBOX_PASSWORD]', 'require_role' => '');

$loginUrl = 'https://www.dropbox.com/ajax_login';
$ch = curl_init($loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                           'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                           'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                          ));

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
if ($result === FALSE)
    $result = curl_error($ch) . ' ' . curl_errno($ch);
```

But I always end up with a 403 Forbidden.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Btw I have a legitimate use case for this. I know that Dropbox uses OAuth 2.0 to prevent the user's password from going to my server. But the credentials which are used here are not from the end-user.

Answer (score 1):

Just complete the OAuth flow once for the target account and save the access token. Then you can use that access token indefinitely.

(If the access token is for the developer account that owns the app, you can skip the OAuth flow altogether and just click the "Generate" button in the app console to get an access token for your own account.)

Comment: This would cover 90% of our use case, if the access token were valid indefinitely. But it isn't, it happens all the time that we get the login page on the server, which would require us to renew the token manually or click the "Generate" button in the app console.

Comment: There must be a way to do this on the server side. Why should it be impossible to do a simple AJAX call via PHP?

Comment: Why does it matter? It would be a lot easier and safer to just use an OAuth token.

Comment: Please, I would not be asking if it didn't matter. We're using Dropbox as a data backend for some virtual users (=mandators). Now every time a token expires, someone has to log in manually and update the token. Again: **Why should it be impossible to do a simple AJAX call via PHP?**

Comment: Dropbox's OAuth access tokens don't expire.

Comment: Apparently you're right, there must be some other reason why our tokens always stop to work. Still, I spent so much time trying to get this running. I'd like to know the answer just out of curiosity.